# Prove that the Moore plane is a completely regular space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that the Moore plane is completely regular space but I don't know where to start
I tried to use the theorem "a space X is completely regular iff it is homemorphic to some subspace of some cube"
But I couldn't prove the homeomorphism

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: FIRST QUESTION REVIEW: good start, but you should add some of your personal trials

Comment: The problem is I could not do any

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/1107523